# How to find the total amount across table with same foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am doing an assignment on managing a shop. The problem I'm having is to display the total money of the item the customer bought in a table. Here are my code

```
create database assingment

use database assignment

    create table Product
(
    ProductID varchar(10),
    PRoductName nvarchar(50),
    Price money,
constraint PK_Product primary key (ProductID)
) 
go

    create table Export
    (
        ExportID varchar(10),
        ImportCompany nvarchar(50),
        Address nvarchar(50),
constraint PK_Export primary key (ExportID)
)
go

    create table ExportDetail
(
    ExportID varchar(10),
    ProductID varchar(10),
    Quantity int,
    constraint FK_ED_E foreign key (ExportID) references Export(ExportID),
    constraint FK_ED_P foreign key (ProductID) references Product(ProductID),
)
go
```

So I want to display the sum of the total (quantity*price) on ExportDetail as the amount on Export. For example:

```
ExportDetail
ExportID  ProductID  Quantity  Total
0234      001        10        10000
0234      002        23        4600
```

the result on Export would be

```
Export
Total 14600
```

Is there a way to display it on the table without using select?

Comment: What is the query you managed to write so far ? Do you have a query which doesn't seem to work ? You tried and got faulty results ? Did you do any research ? 

Or you just expecting someone to write a query for you ?

Comment: what database creates these tables !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: They are from the same database

Comment: @user3417256 - where is your query? We're not here to do your homework for you, we're here to help you understand WHY you are not getting the correct result.